# ScriptSharp ClockLabel example with 0.6.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, script#

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2010 and I've just downloaded and installed Script# 0.6.2 for VS 2010.  I'm trying to follow the clock example in the [Read Me pdf](http://projects.nikhilk.net/Content/Projects/ScriptSharp/ScriptSharp.pdf) but can't get it to compile.

I've created a new Script# Class Library project inside my solution called Clock, renamed the .cs file to ClockBehaviour and added the following code as per the example:

```
using System;
using System.DHTML;
using ScriptFX;
using ScriptFX.UI;

namespace Clock {

    public class ClockBehavior : Behavior {
        private int _intervalCookie;

        public ClockBehavior(DOMElement domElement, string id) : base(domElement, id) {
            _intervalCookie = Window.SetInterval(OnTimer, 1000);
        }

        public override void Dispose() {
            if (_intervalCookie != 0) {
                Window.ClearInterval(_intervalCookie);
            } base.Dispose();
        } private void OnTimer() { DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(); DOMElement.InnerHTML = dateTime.Format("T"); }
    }
}
```

When I try and compile the project I get errors saying that the System.DHMTL, ScriptFX and ScriptFX.UI namespaces could not be found (and some others, but I guess by fixing these errors the others will fall out).

It feels like I'm not referencing the correct projects/dlls.  In the References for the project I have mscorlib and Script.Web.  I've tried using the object browser find the classes (such as Behavior) in other namespaces but with no luck.  I've added all of the .dlls from the ScriptSharp folder in Program Files but the namespaces still can't be found.

Any help would be very much appreciated,
Thanks,
Hugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sample docs are a bit out of date - look at the phot sample in the samples download : http://projects.nikhilk.net/Content/Projects/ScriptSharp/Sample.zip

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've had a look and think I've got my head around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/Conceptual-What

You need to reference `ssfx.Core.dll` which should be installed with Script#

(Alternatively, see pp 23-24 of the pdf you linked...)

Comment: I've looked in C:\Program Files (x86)\ScriptSharp\v1.0 and all sub-folders, but can't find ssfx.Core.dll.  I've run a search on my entire C: drive and can't find it anywhere.  I've tried uninstalling, re-downloading and reinstalling Script# and it still isn't present.  Is there somewhere else I should be getting this .dll from?  In fact none of the .dlls mentioned in the Conceptual-What link are present.

Comment: I haven't got it installed on this machine so can't look but it _may_ be installed in the GAC http://bit.ly/hE4CEv - Failing that, is there a ample project you can download and examine? see what references it uses